# Javascript not showing error

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function registerform(){
    var fullnameExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var firstname= document.getElementById('firstname');
    var lastname= document.getElementById('lastname'); 

    if(firstname.value.match(fullnameExp)){
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML="[Please type in alphabets only!]";
        return false;

    }
    if(lastname.value.match(fullnameExp)){
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML="[Please type in alphabets only!]";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


</script>
</head>
<form method="post" onSubmit = "return registerform();">
<input type='text' id='firstname' size="50" />
<span id="errorname"></span><br>
<input type='text' id='lastname' size="50" />
<span id="errorname"></span><br>

<input type= "Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

what im trying to do here is to validate both my firstname and lastname but then the code only shows error for the first name.why isnt the return working?. did i use return false wrongly. could some one help and explain here

Comment: A `return` statement immediately exits the function. If the first name is bad, you `return false` so no more code in the function runs.

Comment: oh i see. i didnt know that my bad. in this case how would you replace the return with?

Comment: FYI, that regular expression will fail common names.

Comment: that regExp is just an example. im still figuring out the problem

Comment: ... right. I know a guy named "D'Eath" for realz :)  @user3662097 generally you keep a boolean flag.

Comment: solved it thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return statement in first condition ends the method .. So you could just store the valdiation info in variable and return it

```
function registerform(){
    var fullnameExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var firstname= document.getElementById('firstname');
    var lastname= document.getElementById('lastname'); 
    var isValid =true;
    if(firstname.value.match(fullnameExp)){
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML="[Please type in alphabets only!]";
        isValid= false;

    }
    if(lastname.value.match(fullnameExp)){
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML="[Please type in alphabets only!]";
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else{
    document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML="[Please type in alphabets only!]";
    var firstnamevalid = false;

}
if(lastname.value.match(fullnameExp)){}
else{
    document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML="[Please type in alphabets only!]";
    var lastnamevalid =  false;
}
if (!firstnamevalid|| !lastnamevalid)
    return false;
return true;
```

something like this would do what you want I believe.

Essentially as someone mentioned int he comments above, having return statements in your code will immediately exit the method if the method returns something. What this is doing instead is saving your first name and last name validation and then checking to see if either one is false. If it is, THEN you return false and if they're both true then you can return true.

Comment: apologies, I'm still new to javascript. What's wrong with them? I'd be happy to change them if they're incorrect or go against conventions